If $ab$ is in center of a ring, does it mean $ba$ also in center
Let $R$ be a ring and $Z(R)$ is its center. Suppose $ab\in Z(R)$ for some $a,b\in R$. I am trying to prove $ba$ also belongs to $Z(R)$. Given $abr=rab$ for all $r$ in $R$. Now take $bar$, we have to show it equal to $rba$. Should we multiply both sides by $r$ or some other approach?

Why do you think it is true? (It is not)

Take your favorite example of two ring elements $a,b$ with $ab=1$ and $ba \neq 1$. Then $ab$ is central, but we cannot say much about $ba$ except that it's idempotent.
For example, take the ring of endomorphisms of the vector space of sequences, $a$ the left shift, $b$ the right shift. Then $ab=1$, but $ba$ is the idempotent $(x_0,x_1,x_2,\dotsc) \mapsto (0,x_1,x_2,\dotsc)$ and it is not central. In fact for every vector space $V$ over $K$ the center of $\mathrm{End}(V)$ is just $K \cdot \mathrm{id}_V$.
The free ring on two elements $a,b$ with $ab=1$ also works.
